# Inconsistent data in table

Tags: database

A partner where I work have created the customer table with the following fields:

first_name, middle_name, last_name, second_last_name, full_name

Where full_name is the concatenation of the other fields.

Can you give me the best explaining why is a bad practice?

Comment: Typically you want the attributes of a table to be atomic - which means you want them to be in an irreducible state whenever possible.  Suppose someone listed in the table were to get married and their last name changed.  Not only would you have to update the corresponding field `last_name`, but you would also have to rewrite the contents of `full_name`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal because sooner or later, someone or something is going to update `last_name` or `first_name` without updating `full_name`, or vice versa, and you'll have something like this in your database:

```
first_name   last_name   full_name
John         White       John Black
```

And then you get to try to figure out where the discrepancy is coming from and what this guy's last name is really supposed to be, which is no fun. If you're going to [denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) a table like this, there ought to be some compelling reason for doing so. What's your partner's rationale for wanting `full_name` to be a separate field?

You should probably investigate alternatives. For instance, you could define a [view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) that returns the various name components from your table and also assembles them into a `full_name`. Depending on your RDBMS, you may have other options as well. For instance, in SQL Server you can put a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) right into your table.

```
declare @customer table (first_name varchar(50), last_name varchar(50), full_name as first_name + ' ' + last_name);
insert @customer values ('John', 'B');
select * from @customer;
```

Result:

```
first_name   last_name   full_name
John         B           John B
```

Answer (score 0):

If the full_name is persisted on storage, then you got data doubling: you waste twice the storage with no benefits and extra overhead on editing or other maintenance.

If full_name column is actually a function (e.g. it is calculated from the other elements on this row) the solution is fine!

Depending on the database engine you use those calculated columns can only be read (you have to update the other columns to change their outcome), or even be read-write. Writing to such a column is handled by another function, which for example could parse the full name and store the parts in the row, which is to be updated.